# Getting the id of an object added to an indexedDB object store

Tags: indexeddb

Given a indexeddb database with one declared objectstore as:

```
var objectStore = thisDb.createObjectStore("table", {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true})
```

When I add an new item with the add request:

```
var resp = objectStore.add(row)
```

**How can I get the new id of this added item in the onsuccess function?**

```
resp.onsuccess = function(e) { /* code to get the id of the added item */}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the inserted key in e.target.result.

Comment: Is there documentation that states what the `add()` method returns?

Comment: The add method returns an IDBRequest (http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-add-IDBRequest-any-value-any-key) object. But I don't think you will know a lot more with this :). If you take a look at the steps for storing an object (http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-steps-for-storing-a-record-into-an-object-store), you will see at the end that the result of the IDBRequest object is set to the key.